# How many four letter words can be formed using the letterss of the word 'INEFFECTIVE'?

Tags: combinatorics

> How many four letter words can be formed using the letterss of the word 'INEFFECTIVE'?

Please explain with details. Also, how can we clearly differentiate between permutations and combinations?

Comment: I see no way doing this question unless we considered cases

Comment: Actually, I think there is a generator function that you can fill in, but that is overkill..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Letters:-

`C-1
E-3
F-2
I-2
N-1
T-1
V-1`

ABCD type words : $^7C_4\times4!$

ABCC type words : $^3C_1\times^6C_2\times\frac{4!}{2!}$

ABBB type words : $1\times^6C_1\times\frac{4!}{3!}$

AABB type words : $^3C_2\times\frac{4!}{2!\times2!}$

Sum them over to get the total!

NOTE: AABB (for example) means **all** words (including permutations) with 2 letters of one kind and two letters of another type.

Answer (score 2):

There are $11$ letters in 'INEFFECTIVE'.

---

CASE $(1)$: There is only set of three same letters of the letter $E$. So $3$ same letters can be selected in one way. Out of the six remaining distinct letters we can select one in $\binom{6}{1}=6$ ways. Hence there are $6$ groups each of which contains the three same letters. These four letters can be arranged in $\binom{4}{3}=4$ ways. Hence the total number of words with $3$ same and one different letters is $6\times 4=24$ ways.

---

CASE $(2)$: There are $3$ sets of two same letters $E,F,I$. Out of these $3$ sets, two can be selected in $\binom{3}{2}=3$ ways. So there are $3$ groups each of which contains $4$ letters two of which are same of one type and the other two of a different same type. Now $4$ letters in each group can be arranged in $\binom{4}{2}=6$ ways. Hence the total number of words with two letters of one kind and the other two of the different kind is $3\times 6=18$ times.

---

CASE $(3)$: Out of $3$ sets of $2$ same letters one set can be chosen in $\binom{3}{1}=3$ ways. Now from the remaining $6$ letters, $2$ distinct letters can be chosen in $\binom{6}{2}=15$ ways. So there are $3\times 15=45$ groups of $4$ letters each. Now letters of each group can be arranged in $\frac{4!}{2!}=12$ ways. Hence, the total number of ways consisting of two same letters and $2$ different are $45\times 12=540$ ways.

---

CASE $(4)$: There are $\binom{7}{4}$ groups of words with $4$ different letters each. In each group each letter can be arranged in $4!=24$ ways. So the total number of $4$ letter words in which all letters are different is $\binom{7}{4}\times 24=840$ ways.

> There are thus a total of $24+18+540+840=1422$ ways.